Численно определить, зависит ли данное выражение от некоторой переменной
Собственно, вопрос в заголовке.
Например:
struct X
{
    double a{};
    double b{};
    double c{};
    // ... some function and variable declarations

    double f()
    {
        double result{};
        // some calculations
        return result;
    }
}

Каким образом выяснить, зависит ли f() от a или от b или от c ...?
Простейшее решение - вычислить в двух (или более) различных точках и сравнить результат, но хотелось бы более строгое решение найти.

Простейшее решение в общем случае не проходит.

именно поэтому я и задаю вопрос.

А что-то вообще известно о функции или это полностью "чёрный ящик"? Потому что если это сферический чёрный ящик в вакууме, то там может быть любая засада, типа того, что на почти всём диапазоне параметров функция не зависит от переменной a, но при каком-то волшебном сочетании параметров вдруг зависит. И найти это можно только полным перебором всех значений параметров, что в общем случае не реально. То есть нужна какая-то дополнительная инфа о природе функции. А если функция, например, линейная, то пары точек по каждой координате будет достаточно, видимо.

@CrazyElf функция непрерывна и дифференцируема на исследуемых участках (по каждой интересующей переменной). При необходимости, можно наложить необходимые дополнительные условия.

т.е. имеется ввиду, что все входящие в f() функции и выражения обладают необходимыми условиями

@hermann.minkowski Я учился в ВУЗ-е почти 30 лет назад, но думаю тут нужно копать в сторону частных производных и численного дифференцирования )

@CrazyElf найти численную производную не проблема. Надо еще доказать, что она всюду равна нулю

Если функция задана одим выражением (без if, while, for и т.п.), то задайте всем переменным какие-нибудь значения и подберите их так чтобы функция вернула не NaN. Затем замените значение интересующей вас переменной на NaN. Если функция вернёт NaN, она зависит от этой переменной.

@StanislavVolodarskiy интересный ход. Подумаю, спасибо за наводку

@StanislavVolodarskiy Мысль интересная, я её тоже думал, но ведь double не nullable вроде? Хотя смотря что это за язык вообще, тега то нет ))

@CrazyElf Так NaN это число

@CrazyElf C++. Язык не указал, т.к. отсеял бы знающих ответ людей, но не интересующихся данным языком

@AlexeyTen А, точно, Python меня испортил, в C# всё есть, да ))  И бесконечности и NaN. Это не null, точно. А вот как в C++ я даже и не знаю.

устроит решение на любом языке. Адаптирую

Есть еще предложение - прогонять текст всех выражений через лексический анализатор и составлять список входящих в них переменных. Но это уж слишком ...

@CrazyElf везде где используется IEEE754 (т.е. практически везде) есть NaN. Даже в питоне.

@hermann.minkowski хм, function f(x) { return x - x; } по факту не зависит от x, но лексически зависит… Правда проверку через NaN она тоже не пройдёт

@AlexeyTen я ждал этого вопроса. Интересует математическая зависимость

Но кажется численно только тыкать в случайные точки и надеяться на лучшее. Потому что легко можно сделать бесконечно-дифференцируемую функцию отличную от нуля только в каком-то отрезке и если случайно в него не попасть, то можно подумать что это просто ноль.

Если нужна именно математическая зависимость и есть доступ к тексту функции, то этот текст можно преобразовать и передать в систему компьютерной алгебры. Она определит зависимости, когда это возможно. И нет, это не слишком. Нормально задача решается модификацией компилятора. Но она и не всегда разрешима, её можно свести к проблеме остановки.
